# Angularjs: date expiration for $cacheFactory

Tags: caching, angularjs, browser-cache

I have added cache in my application with $cacheFactory, but when the user close the browser and then reopen, the cache data about the browsed products is expired.

Are there any way to make it longer? put a date of expiration or something like that?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I would maybe have to use [Breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/), but before this I wanted to know if any of you know if it is possible to do it with angularjs (I read the API and there is no info about it :S).

**Edit 2:** to help, the way in which I use $cacheFactory is like this [JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/yYEXN/).

```
factory('SomeCache', function($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('someCache', {
        capacity: 3 // optional - turns the cache into LRU cache
    });
}).
```

**Edit 3:** Lawnchair is not an option, it stores in a javascript array and doesn't persists the data after closing the browser..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$cacheFactory uses in-memory browser storage, which means it doesn't persist across even a page refresh, let alone closing and re-opening the browser.

If you want to cache data across page loads and browser sessions, you're looking for localStorage. See here for a very simple example:

http://jsbin.com/acokis/2/edit

I think you'll want to look at [amplify.js](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/) or [lawnchair.js](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) as they provide nice wrappers for managing localStorage, also also provide fallback adapters for browsers that don't support localStorage (fallback options won't persist across page refreshes though).

Comment: for just store info maybe lawnchair can fit what I need, breeze seems more advanced, maybe too much for what we simply need.. thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer. localStorage persists after you close your browser _if_ the browser supports it. Libraries like Lawnchair/Amplify make working with localStorage easier.