# angularjs cacheFactory is empty

Tags: angularjs

I store some keys in cache using angularJs cachefactory

```
myApp.factory('SomeCache', function ($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('someCache', {
        capacity: 10 // optional - turns the cache into LRU cache
    });
});
```

in the code :

```
SomeCache.put(key, value);
```

I see all the keys and values in the console.
The problem is , when i redirect to another page, not in my webSite ( e.c www.ebay.com)
and the i come back the cache object is empty, 
I needd to preserve the data on the page.

Any idea ? 
ishay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you see with $cacheFactory is expected. The AngularJS-Cache does not persist between page refreshes. See also: [Angularjs: date expiration for $cacheFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15656829/669561)

What you need to use to persist data between page refreshes is localStorage or sessionStorage as explained on this site: [DOM Storage guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

You should use the excellent [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) module.

Comment: heh, I was halfway through typing this exact answer.